# how to train model in which labels is [5,30]?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, nlp, keras-layer

How to train on a dataset which has each label of shape **[5,30]**. For example :

```
[
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 54, 55, 21, 56, 57,  3,
        22, 19, 58,  6, 59,  4, 60,  1, 61, 62, 23, 63, 23, 64],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
         0,  0,  0,  0,  1, 65,  7, 66,  2, 67, 68,  3, 69, 70],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
         0, 11, 12,  5, 13, 14,  9, 10,  5, 15, 16, 17,  2,  8],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  2, 71,  1, 72, 73, 74,  7, 75, 76, 77,  3,
        20, 78, 18, 79,  1, 21, 80, 81,  3, 82, 83, 84,  6, 85],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  2,
        86, 87,  3, 88, 89,  1, 90, 91, 22, 92, 93,  4,  6, 94]
]
```

One way was to reshape the labels to [150], but that will make the **tokenized sentences** lose their meanings. Please suggest me how to arrange the **keras layers** and which layers to be able to make the model? I want to able to generate sentences later.

My code for model right now is this.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([ feature_layer, 
layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'), 
layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'), 
layers.Dropout(.1), 
layers.Dense(5), 
layers.Dense(30, activation='softmax'), ]) 
opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.01) 
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mean_absolute_percentage_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The actual data.

| state | district | month | rainfall | max_temp | min_temp | max_rh | min_rh | wind_speed | advice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Orissa | Kendrapada | february | 0.0 | 34.6 | 19.4 | 88.2 | 29.6 | 12.0 | chances of foot rot disease in paddy crop; apply urea at 3 weeks after transplanting at active tillering stage for paddy;...... |
| Jharkhand | Saraikela Kharsawan | february | 0 | 35.2 | 16.6 | 29.4 | 11.2 | 3.6 | provide straw mulch and go for intercultural operations to avoid moisture losses from soil; chance of leaf blight disease in potato crop; ....... |

I need to be able to generate the advices.

Comment: I think it's better if you add in some code that makes debugging easier, do you have any code prepared?

Comment: But from your comment the targeted output you can make a simple dense layer for the targetd output as so tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, activation='softmax')

Comment: It returns this error.
Incompatible shapes: [10,5,30] vs. [10,30]

Comment: I have added the code right now in my question.

Comment: Can you specify some information like what is your input like?? With a sample input and target in their original format

Comment: Okay. I am adding that here also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do consider that the output needs to be in this shape (and not flattened), the easiest (and also correct solution in my opinion) is to have a multi-output network, each output having a `layers.Dense(30,activation='softmax')`.

You would have something like:

```
def create_model():
    base_model = .... (stacked Dense units + other) # you can even create multi-input multi-output if you really want that.
    first_output = Dense(30,activation='softmax',name='output_1')(base_model) 
    second_output = Dense(30,activation='softmax',name='output_2')(base_model)
    ...
    fifth_output = Dense(30,activation='softmax',name='output_5')(base_model)
    model = Model(inputs=input_layer,
                  outputs=[first_output,second_output,third_output,fourth_output,fifth_output])
    return model


optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss={'output_1': 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
                    'output_2': 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                    'output_3': 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                    'output_4': 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                    'output_5': 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'},
              metrics={'output_1':tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(),
                       'output_2':tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(),
                       'output_3':tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(),
                       'output_4':tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(),
                       'output_5':tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()})

model.fit(X, y,
          epochs=100, batch_size=10, validation_data=(val_X, val_y))
```

Here, note that y (both for train and valid) is a a numpy array of length 5 (number of outputs) and each element has length 30.

Again, ensure that you actually need such a configuration; I posted the answer as a demonstration of multi-output label in TensorFlow and Keras and for the benefit of the others, but I am not 100% sure you actually need this exact configuration (perhaps you can opt for something easier).

Note the usage of `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`, since your labels are not one-hot encoded (also MAPE is for regression, not classification).

Comment: Can you give an example how the base_model should look in code

Comment: Have a look here: https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-output-model-with-tensorflow-keras-functional-api-875dd89aa7c6

Comment: Yeah. I got it with some work around and now I can change the layers later also. Thanks man.

Comment: You are welcome, should you have any more questions please ask, although StackOverflow rules do state that you should ask questions in another post not as a commentary.